# Showing properties of polynomials given by a two-term recursion.

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

I'm currently dealing with the following kind of two-term recursion for real polynomials $p_{k}(x)$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
 p_{0}(x) &=& 1, \\
 p_{1}(x) &=& 1-2x, \\
 p_{k+1}(x) &=& -p_{k-1}(x) + p_{k}(x)\left(2 - 4x\right).
\end{eqnarray}

Rewinding the recursion for the first few polynomials would give the following expanded forms:
\begin{eqnarray}
 p_{2}(x) &=& 1 - 8 x + 8 x^2, \\
 p_{3}(x) &=& 1 - 18 x + 48 x^2 - 32 x^3, \\
 p_{4}(x) &=& 1 - 32 x + 160 x^2 - 256 x^3 + 128 x^4, \\
 p_{5}(x) &=& 1 - 50 x + 400 x^2 - 1120 x^3 + 1280 x^4 - 512 x^5 \\
 p_{6}(x) &=& 1 - 72 x + 840 x^2 - 3584 x^3 + 6912 x^4 - 6144 x^5 + 2048 x^6.
\end{eqnarray}
[Graph of the first four polynomials.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTDRf.png)

The above plots lead to the conclusion that all roots are within the interval $(0,1)$ and that $|p_{k}(x)| \leq 1$, if $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Does anyone know a good way to actually verify/proof the above hypothesis for this kind of two-term recursion?

Comment: To show all roots are in (0,1) use induction to show that  $p_k(x) \ge p_{k-1}(x) \ge \cdots \ge p_0(x) \ge 1$ for $x < 0$ and $p_{2k}(x) \ge -p_{2k-1}(x) \ge \cdots \ge -p_1(x) \ge p_0(x) \ge 1$ for $x > 1$.